# Add Multiple Lists <T> To DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, datatable

I'm struggling to figure out how I can add (in my case 3 lists) to a DataTable so I can output it on my GridView.

I have the following Lists

1. List Name  (Content number of string)
2. List Number   (Content number of integers)
3. List Status (Content number of string)

Ideally I would like to have the following result in DataTable

Name (Column 1)  : Content Of List 1
Number(Column 2) : Content of List 2
Status(Column 3) : Content of List 3

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me here, as I haven't found much on the net. Please do ask if it isn't clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example illustrating how this would work with data?

Comment: why do you have 3 separate lists.. is all the information that you are seeking coming from one `DataSource` please edit this question and show an illustration of what you are working with or trying to do

Comment: Sure, Well I have 3 methods, each method returning a list as mentioned above. Now my struggle is that I don't know how I can fill the DataTable with the lists returned. I'm not sure what you want to see but I'm retrieving data via LINQ from 3 different tables and have to now show them in one Grid. Does that make sense?

Comment: well there are many things that you can do with linq to return a custom list that then you could bind to a datagrid.. link supports things such as .ToList(), Join, etc.. but once again you are not providing enough information.. why can't you do a simple query that joins the data that you need and return that datatable or dataset and bind it to a Datagrid...? there are a `1000` ways to skin this cat..

Answer (score 1):

That depends on couple of things,

- All the list have same number of items
- The order of elements in the lists are same as well, for example, on index 0, you have Name in `NameList`, on index 0 of `NumberList`, you have relevant number and so on.

With this you can use a single loop and add rows to your DataTable (`dt`) like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NameList.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(NameList[i], NumberList[i], StatusList[i]);
}
```

Assuming you have `DataTable` in place with three columns like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof (string));
dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof (string));
```

A better approach, would be to have list of a custom object, where your object would have properties, Name, Number, Status. Populate that List, instead of maintaining three different lists based on index.

Comment: that's assuming that he's created the `DataTable and Datarow`

Comment: `DataTable` , Yes, but there is no need to create `DataRow` explicitly using `dt.NewRow()`, as long as the columns are defined, `Rows.Add` will add the values to the data table.

Comment: I agree with you I was only making that comment in regards to if the `OP` didn't understand what you have written initially that's all .. however I think that the op is over thinking there own process